# Node.js - Express.io: Different session saving in different browsers

Tags: node.js, express, session-variables

How and if sessions are correct saved differs in node.js' express.io (all in the latest version) from different browsers.
How could I fix this misbehavior?

Code:

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    req.session.variable = 'value';
    req.session.save(function() {
        console.log(req.session);
    });
    res.send('<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>\
              <script>var socket = io.connect();</script>\
              Home content');
});

app.io.route('disconnect', function(req) {
    console.log('-------------------------------');
    console.log(req.session);
    req.session.variable = '';
    req.session.save(function() {
        console.log(req.session);
        console.log('-------------------------------');
    });
});
```

Situation:
I'm on the `/home` page and I reload the page.
The output of the console in every(?) browser except Chrome after reload:

```
{ cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: Mon May 19 2014 01:40:59 GMT+0200,
     originalMaxAge: 31536000000,
     httpOnly: true },
  variable: 'value' }

// RELOAD:

-------------------------------
{ cookie:
   { originalMaxAge: 31536000000,
     expires: '2014-05-18T23:40:59.399Z',
     httpOnly: true,
     path: '/' },
  variable: 'value',
  touch: [Function],
  resetMaxAge: [Function],
  save: [Function],
  reload: [Function],
  destroy: [Function],
  regenerate: [Function] }
{ cookie:
   { originalMaxAge: 31536000000,
     expires: '2014-05-18T23:40:59.399Z',
     httpOnly: true,
     path: '/' },
  variable: '',
  touch: [Function],
  resetMaxAge: [Function],
  save: [Function],
  reload: [Function],
  destroy: [Function],
  regenerate: [Function] }
-------------------------------
{ cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: Mon May 19 2014 01:41:03 GMT+0200,
     originalMaxAge: 31536000000,
     httpOnly: true },
  variable: 'value' }
```

In Chrome:

```
{ cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: Mon May 19 2014 00:43:37 GMT+0200,
     originalMaxAge: 31536000000,
     httpOnly: true },
  variable: 'value' }

// RELOAD

{ cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: Mon May 19 2014 00:43:37 GMT+0200,
     originalMaxAge: 31536000000,
     httpOnly: true },
  variable: 'value' }
-------------------------------
{ cookie:
   { originalMaxAge: 31536000000,
     expires: '2014-05-18T23:36:58.926Z',
     httpOnly: true,
     path: '/' },
  variable: 'value',
  touch: [Function],
  resetMaxAge: [Function],
  save: [Function],
  reload: [Function],
  destroy: [Function],
  regenerate: [Function] }
{ cookie:
   { originalMaxAge: 31536000000,
     expires: '2014-05-18T23:36:58.926Z',
     httpOnly: true,
     path: '/' },
  variable: '',
  touch: [Function],
  resetMaxAge: [Function],
  save: [Function],
  reload: [Function],
  destroy: [Function],
  regenerate: [Function] }
-------------------------------
```

May this be a bug of Chrome and not express.io?
It's also weird that the log order is different in Chrome than any other browser.

What I need is that a session variable should be deleted/empty if a user navigates away from a certain page (which sets that variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem long time ago by setting this setting to sync the disconnect on unload on the client side like that:

```
var socket = io.connect('your-socket-url.com', {
    'sync disconnect on unload': true
});
```